# how should the compilation be done to be included in ant _home lib for .class and java file

Tags: ant, jar

i have a problem ant script:

```
<taskdef name="CFileEdit" classname="com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit"/>
```

where taskdef class com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit cannot be found

now i have CFileEdit.java and i did this:

1. CFileEdit.java compiled into CFiledEdit.class
2. CFileEdit.class into CFileEdit.jar
3. Place CFileEdit.jar into ANT_HOME\lib?

I am not sure if step 3 is correct. I do not wish to add a path in my ant script. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a classpath for the taskdef (example for svnkit):

```
<taskdef name="svnkit" 
    className="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask"
    classpathref="svnkit.classpath" />

  <path id="svnkit.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${3rd.lib.dir}/svnant/svnant/1.3.0/" >
      <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>  
  </path>
```

-EDIT-
If you don't want to alter the taskdef you can choose one of the following options to place the jar (from : http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html):

> In ANT_HOME/lib. This makes the JAR
>   files available to all Ant users and
>   builds.
>
> In ${user.home}/.ant/lib (as of Ant
>   1.6). This allows different users to add new libraries to Ant. All JAR
>   files added to this directory are
>   available to command-line Ant.
>
> On the command line with a -lib
>   parameter. This lets you add new JAR
>   files on a case-by-case basis.
>
> In the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>   Avoid this; it makes the JAR files
>   visible to all Java applications, and
>   causes no end of support calls. See
>   below for details.

Comment: i guess this is correct but i dont really wish to edit my ant script

Comment: how about the naming syntax with regards to your edited answer? is mine correct?

Comment: @jeremychan there is no required naming syntax for custom ant tasks. But at a closer look your class must be in the directory com/ANT_Tasks/ in the jar File (accoring to the package definition of your class). More Details are found here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html